Is it possible to use an ssl certificate authentication through an http proxy
I have a Java application (Spring boot, webflux) that use a webclient with a reactor connector to make an https request to another server.
This server require mutual TLS authentication so i have configured an sslContext on the webclient and everything works fine.
However my application needs to go through a proxy to make externals calls, but when i configure the webclient to go through a proxy (tinyproxy, but i tried squid and got the same result) there is an ssl handshake error.
Here's the webclient code (works without the proxy) :
            String keystore = Files.readString(Paths.get("/my-keystore.p12"));
            InputStream keystoreInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(keystore);
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

            keyStore.load(keystoreInputStream, "keystore-pass");

            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "my-pass");

            SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                    .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
                    .build();

            WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("external-service-url")
                .clientConnector(
                        new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                                HttpClient.create()
                                        .secure(sslSpec -> sslSpec.sslContext(sslContext))
                                        .proxy(
                                             proxySpec -> proxySpec
                                            .type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
                                            .host("my-proxy-host")
                                            .port(Integer.parseInt(3128))
                            )
                        )
                );

When using -Djavax.net.debug=all there's a lot of output but i think the interesting part is that without the proxy i have :
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 51|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:07:30.250 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:434|Unsupported signature scheme: dsa_sha384
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 51|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:07:30.250 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:434|Unsupported signature scheme: dsa_sha512
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 51|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:07:30.250 CEST|SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:388|matching alias: my-cert

and with the proxy :
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.166 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:434|Unsupported signature scheme: dsa_sha384
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.166 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:434|Unsupported signature scheme: dsa_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.166 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.166 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:821|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.166 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.166 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:821|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:821|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:821|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:821|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:821|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:821|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:821|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:821|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:821|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:831|No available authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:176|Raw read (
  0000: XXXXXXXXXX                       .........
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.167 CEST|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:213|READ: TLSv1.2 handshake, length = 4
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.168 CEST|ServerHelloDone.java:151|Consuming ServerHelloDone handshake message (
<empty>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.168 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:299|No X.509 certificate for client authentication, use empty Certificate message instead
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.168 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:330|Produced client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": <empty list>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.171 CEST|ECDHClientKeyExchange.java:407|Produced ECDHE ClientKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ClientKeyExchange": {
  "ecdh public": {
    XXXXXXX                                          .
  },
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.175 CEST|ChangeCipherSpec.java:115|Produced ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.175 CEST|Finished.java:396|Produced client Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: XXXXXXX
  }'}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.175 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:530|WRITE: TLSv1.2 handshake, length = 77
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.176 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:551|Raw write (
  0000: XXXXXX                                            ..
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.176 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:530|WRITE: TLSv1.2 change_cipher_spec, length = 1
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.176 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:551|Raw write (
  0000: XXXXXXX                                ......
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.176 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:530|WRITE: TLSv1.2 handshake, length = 16
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.176 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1773|Plaintext before ENCRYPTION (
  0000: XXXXX
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.176 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:551|Raw write (
  0000: XXXXX
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.218 CEST|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:176|Raw read (
  0000: XXXXXXX                            ......(
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.218 CEST|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:213|READ: TLSv1.2 alert, length = 2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 01|reactor-http-epoll-5|2024-06-03 15:05:32.219 CEST|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
)

If i understand all this correctly, when the proxy is enabled the jvm can't seems to find the certificate to use for authentication, but i have no idea why (or if this is even possible through a http proxy).

"No X.509 certificate for client authentication" - This indicates that your client is not properly configured to provide the requested certificate. Is this really the same client with the same key store against the same server and the only change is using a proxy?

I can assure you that without the proxy the webclient successfully authenticate to the remote server.
Also, i'm testing with the proxy installed directly on my computer, so i don't think it's a no network issue like a firewall messing up the connexion or something like that.

A simple HTTP proxy (without SSL interception) will just pass through the original TLS handshake without any modification.  I can see that the server asks for a client certificate. I can also see that the client does not find one and thus fills in an empty certificate. If the server is the same, the key store is the same and the URL used to access the server is the same and the only difference is the proxy (which does not change anything in the TLS handshake) I would the client expect to find the same client certificate in it as it does w/o proxy.

You are absolutely right ... there was a condition in my code to only set the proxy on the client when there the proxy host is not blank, but in the process of setting the proxy i was calling HttpClient.create() and thus creating a new instance without the sslContext (i did not include this part of the code for the readability of the post).
Thanks and sorry for the waste of time !

Regarding your concret question, the answer is that of course it is possible to use mutual auth TLS together with a proxy.
However, to find out why your approach does not work, more information is required. Your logs don't show the TLS handshake error. Furthermore, we don't know the configuration of your proxy server. So I can only guess. Maybe your proxy server is configured to intercept the TLS communication and something doesn't work properly on that side?

You are right, i added more log until the ssl handshake error (replaced some data for security reason with XXXX).
I did not customized the configuration of the proxy (either tinyproxy or squid), to be honest i don't really know what to look for.
